# Confirm before leave directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

This directive uses SweetAlert just as replacement of confirm() js function.
https://jsfiddle.net/alfredopacino/njccccsh/

```
app.directive('confirmLeave',function(){
return {
    restrict:"A",
    controller:function($scope,$attrs,SweetAlert,$state,$location){
        $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
            window.onbeforeunload = undefined;
        });
        $scope.$parent.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
            console.log($scope.formname.$dirty)

            if($scope.formname.$dirty){
            event.preventDefault()
                SweetAlert.swal({
                        title: "Are you sure you want to leave this page?",
                        text: "Some changes have not been saved.",
                        type: "warning",
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",confirmButtonText: "Ok",
                        cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
                        closeOnConfirm: true,
                        closeOnCancel: true },
                    function(isConfirm){
                        if (isConfirm) {
                            console.log(next.name)
                            $state.go(next.name)
                            //$location.path(next.name)
                        }
                    });

            }

        });
    }
}});
```

It checks the form dirty state and it should follow the next route in case of confirm, but that $state.go() doesn't redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the SweetAlert was "firing" even on your `$state.go` function and not letting the state change but not showing the alert the second time.

I made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dor2detj/1/

In the fiddle I have added a little timeout (you can remove the timeout, it's there just for the following example) for the `$state.go` function and if your remove the isconfirmed part in this code:

```
if($scope.formname.$dirty && isconfirmed === false){
  ...
}
```

you can see that it fires the SweetAlert again.

The solution is to set a variable which I named here `isconfirmed` which prevents the SweetAlert from firing again.

Further down the road you can use the `ng-change` in the textarea/input/form to set the variable `isconfirmed` to false again to make the alert popup again if the user changes the input.

Hopefully you can get your code working based on this example.